# Should users receive a notification when they are being rated poorly?

Tags: user-behavior, email, notification, ratings

I'm working on this cleaning services marketplace and we've decided to implement a two sided rating system.

Since a few customers are being disrespectful to the cleaners, we are implementing some rules in which the customer could be reported because of their bad behaviors.

Even thought, I'm not sure if we should tell them when they are being reported for the first time.

On one hand, they could change their manners accordingly to get in a respectful relationship with their cleaners, on the other, I'm not sure if that could discourage them of using the platform after that (even thought that report could be false).

I hope I explained enough this problem, and I haven't been able to find any research work on anything similar

Answer (score 4):

A similar kind of rating system is followed in Uber taxi hailing service. The users have to rate a driver after the ride ends similarly the driver also have to give ratings to the user. This rating system helps the company to send out weekly summaries and letting drivers know how to improve their rating. (http://therideshareguy.com/one-quick-tip-to-boost-your-uber-driver-rating/)

But the user rating is visible to the particular user in this app in a place where some user know it even exists (https://vulcanpost.com/427182/how-check-your-rating-uber/) which makes no change in the user behaviour. But allowing the user to view their rating in a place where it is easily accessible have both positive and negative impacts. As you have mentioned the user might not come back to use the application or it could probably help the user to change their behaviour.

My suggestion is to make the rating visible to the user only after few services is over, say 10 services and provide the average rating of the 10 services. This makes no vengeance on the service person who rated badly as the user could not find who rated badly unless the same person is attending for all the services.

You can also provide discounts to the highly rated user to improve their behaviour towards the service person. Also, the service employees will also be happy to attend such users which boost employee satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think rating on the spot at each service would be great for the customers as well as service providers. When the service provider is aware of this upfront rating system, he will tend to impress his customers by providing a good service to get good ratings. Along with the rating there should be comments(optional) section to the customers to show there concerns. But this concerns(comments) should not be visible by the service providers. This concerns raised by the customers should be viewed by marketplace owners and tell the service provider in different approach.